# JSON array start with several Array

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to create JSON feed from one site which i want to decode on another. The problem is there seem to be to many array[0], so it is hard to loop through it and count how many objects there are.

How can i do this encode and decode without getting all these arrays, to make it easier to count the amount of objects and loop through it.

at the moment i'm encoding it like this:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $r = str_replace("\n",'', shorten_txt($post->post_content, 500));
    $n = str_replace("\r", '', $r);
    $post_data = array(
    'title' => get_the_title($post->ID),
    'link' => get_permalink($post->ID),
    'image' => catch_that_image(),
    'content' => $n,
    'time' => get_the_date( $d)." ". get_the_time( $d));
     $data[] = (array('item' => $post_data));

}
echo json_encode($data);
```

This gives this output:

```
[
    {
        item: {
            title: "Hello world!",
            link: "http://URL/wordpress/?p=1",
            image: "http://URL/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Digital-Board-2.png",
            content: "Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it,             then start blogging!",
            time: "April 17, 2014 5:32 pm"
        }
    }
]
```

When i decode this i get this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [item] => Array( [title] => Hello world! [link] => http://URL/wordpress/?p=1 [image] => http://URL/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Digital-Board-2.png [content] => Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging! Jeg elsker kage [time] => April 17, 2014 5:32 pm ) ) )
```

The decode code:

```
$json_string = 'http://95.85.11.40/wordpress/?page_id=20';

$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$obj = json_decode($jsondata, true);
print_r($obj);
```

Comment: is `echo json_encode($data[0]);` ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want those `array[0]` bits, then don't create a 2D array:

```
$data[] = (array('item' => $post_data));
```

Should then be:

```
$data[] = $post_data;
```

Your current statement read as _add to array `$data` an array, with 1 key: *"item"*, whereas my version just says: *add to `$data` the value of `$post_data`*.

loping oiver decoded data:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($jsonFile), true);
foreach ($data as $idx => $item)
{
    echo 'This is item number ', $idx +1, PHP_EOL;
    print_r($item);
}
```